# Rails4 and Cocoon - How to Handle Has_One Relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to deal with nested forms in my Rails4 application but I'm having problems with has_one relationship because all the GEM documentation is only for has_many. When I try to create a new examination the app is throwing "Unpermitted parameters: exam_statuses" message. Probably I'm doing something wrong with singular&plural names but can you please check what is wrong with this code. Here is my codes;

**examination.rb:**

```
class Examination < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :exam_status, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :exam_status, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

**examination_controller.rb:**

```
  .....
  def new
    @examination = Examination.new
  end

  def create
    @examination = Examination.new(examination_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @examination.save
        format.html { redirect_to examinations_path, notice: 'success' }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
      end
    end
  end

  private
    def set_examination
      @examination = Examination.find(params[:id])
    end

    def examination_params
      params.require(:examination).permit(:name, :shortname, :fee, :exam_status => [:first_application_date, :last_application_date, :examination_id])
    end
```

**views/examinations/new.html.erb =>**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@examination) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.input :shortname %>
  <%= f.input :fee %>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :exam_status do |exam_status| %>
    <%= render 'exam_status_fields', :f => exam_status %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**views/examinations/_exam_status_fields.html.erb =>**

```
<div class="nested-fields">
  <%= f.input :first_application_date, as: :datetime %>
  <%= f.input :last_application_date, as: :datetime %>
  <%= f.input :examination_id %>
</div>
```

**Log File =>**

```
Started POST "/examinations" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:43:30 +0300
Processing by ExaminationsController#create as HTML

Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", 

"authenticity_token"=>"uYpiZ9Z1txaJ1mib+NEAG7Ckwm9F3TyNQ6jRpYz3ncA=",
"examination"=>{"name"=>"nnnnn", "shortname"=>"nnnnnn", "fee"=>"33", 

"exam_statuses"=>{"first_application_date(3i)"=>"3", "first_application_date(2i)"=>"7", "first_application_date(1i)"=>"2014", "first_application_date(4i)"=>"16", "first_application_date(5i)"=>"43", "last_application_date(3i)"=>"5", "last_application_date(2i)"=>"7", "last_application_date(1i)"=>"2014", "last_application_date(4i)"=>"16", "last_application_date(5i)"=>"43", "examination_id"=>""}}}

Unpermitted parameters: exam_statuses
```

Comment: exam_statuses doesn't match exam_status.

Comment: Yes its obvious! So what is the answer? Not the reason.

Comment: Did you try changing exam_status to exam_statuses in 
`def examination_params`

Comment: Why is this question tagged both [tag:ruby-on-rails-3] and [tag:ruby-on-rails-4]?

Comment: Why did you tag this question with cocoon-gem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few issues here.

**1. Controller**

In your `new` method you need to build `exam_status` for `examination`:

```
# GET /examinations/new
def new
  @examination = Examination.new
  @examination.build_exam_status
end
```

And in your `examination_params` method, you need to change it to:

```
def examination_params
  params.require(:examination).permit(:name, :shortname, :fee, exam_status_attributes: [:first_application_date, :last_application_date, :_destroy])
end
```

Notice that `:exam_status` needs to be `exam_status_attributes` and it doesn't need `examination_id` param (Rails takes care of that). Also note that I added `_destroy`. This is a flag used to destroy the object.

**2. Nested fields partial**

Remove `examination_id` field from the partial.

```
<div class="nested-fields">
  <%= f.input :first_application_date, as: :datetime %>
  <%= f.input :last_application_date, as: :datetime %>
</div>
```

These changes will take care of the issue.

Comment: Thank you sir! It is working great and your explanation was perfect. Thanks.